# redirecting to google translation onchange of options of a cloned select menu (ScrollectBox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, google-translate, select-menu

i'm trying to integrate google translation using the following plugin:

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/index.html

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js

i'm calling the cloned select menu together with the translation function in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            var selectEvent = function($el){    
            Translate(this); // This is the function of translation script
            return false; 
            };
         $(".selection").scrollectBox({
            preset: 'dropdown',
            numVisibleOptions: 4,
            scrollInterval: 150, 
              onSelectEvent: selectEvent,
                scrollOn: 'hover',
          listWidth: 160
});
});
</script>
```

the example of select menu that redirects a page to google translate on change of options is as following:

```
<div id = "translate">
<select onchange="Translate(this)" name="select" id="site-translator" class="selection" >
         <option value="Select Language">Select Language</option>
         <option value="en|af">Afrikaans</option>
         <option value="en|sq">Albanian</option>
         <option value="en|ar">Arabic</option>
         <option value="en|hy">Armenian</option><option value="en|az">Azerbaijani</option>
         <option value="en|eu">Basque</option></option>
         </select>
```

the original select menu performs it's task well whereas the cloned select menu is unable to redirect the page to google translator.

the demonstrations of original select menu & clone select menu are given below:

is anyone well aware about the limitation or scope of this cloned select menu. why the page isn't redirected to google translator through it?

any idea shall be welcomed.